# SPServices simple query does not work

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spservices

I have the following code and it does not work. 
Apparently it's all right. 
The List name and the URL.

Can anyone help me find the syntax error?

PS: I use Sharepoint Foundation 2010

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: 'GetListItems',
  async: false,
  listName: 'MyList_Name',
  webURL: 'http://domain.com/', 
  CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields>'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="NamePage" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="Date" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="Title" />'+
                '<ViewFields>',
  CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='FALSE'></OrderBy></Query>",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status){

    htmlReturn += '<div class="coluns">';

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function() {
        var Title = $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
            Date = $(this).attr('ows_Date'),
            NamePage = $(this).attr('ows_NamePage');

        if(aux <= 6){
            htmlReturn +=  '<ul>'+
                                '<li class="date">'+Date+'</li>'+
                                '<li><a href="'+NamePage+'.aspx">'+Title+'</a></li>'+
                            '</ul>';
            aux++;
        }
    });
    htmlReturn+= '</div>';

    if(htmlReturn != ''){
        $('.Result').html(htmlReturn);
    }else{
        $('.Result').html('');
    }
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields>'+
                '<FieldRef Name="NamePage" />'+
                '<FieldRef Name="Date" />'+
                '<FieldRef Name="Title" />'+
            '<ViewFields>'
```

should be

```
CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields>'+
                '<FieldRef Name="NamePage" />'+
                '<FieldRef Name="Date" />'+
                '<FieldRef Name="Title" />'+
            '</ViewFields>'
```

note the `/`on the last `ViewFields`

Also, this

```
"<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='FALSE'></OrderBy></Query>",
```

should be

```
"<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query>",
```

note the `/` after `Ascending='FALSE'`

Comment: Thank u.. It worked :D

Comment: Glad to hear that!